# failed to compute cache key: "/nginx/default" not found: not found

Tags: docker

I was trying to copy a file from parent directory but I am getting error "failed to compute cache key: "/nginx/default" not found: not found"

What I did is COPY ["../nginx/default", "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled"].

Thanks for all the helps

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T0UZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an image, you have a 'build context' which usually is the directory of where the Dockerfile is. The build context is that directory and all directories below that directory.

For security reasons, a Dockerfile is not allowed to access files outside of the build context.

When you try to go up a directory with '../nginx/default', you move outside the build context, and that's not allowed.

You can either move your nginx config file so it is inside the build context, or you can move the Dockerfile up a level, so you can do

```
COPY ["./nginx/default", "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled"]
```

Comment: okay got it thanks Hans

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Docker are you using? When I do the same, I get `COPY failed: forbidden path outside the build context` which is a much better error message. I'm on version 20.10.12 on Ubuntu. Also, if my answer helped you, can you mark it as accepted, please?

Comment: I have Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d on windows. I think I have to update mine.